# vb6 can't open a connection obj that used to work perfectly

Tags: vb6, connection-string, adodb

This code is in an ActiveX .dll. For a year this connection worked perfectly, now it doesn't. Here's the code:

```
Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim objRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim theConnectionStr As String

Dim SanMarDB As Databas
Dim SanMarRs As Recordse
.
.
.
    Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    theConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                       "Data Source=" & gProgramFilesPath & ";" & _
                       "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1'"
    objConnection.Open theConnectionStr
```

Here is my list of references in the .dll:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures
- Visual Basic objects and procedures
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library 6.0 (SP6)
- Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

I get one of two error messages. Here's the first

> Invalid setting in Excel key of the Engines section of the Windows Registry.

Google pointed me to some reasons for this error message and I've checked the registry setting and it appears correct, CSVDelimited, no 5-char entries, etc.

The second error message is:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

The thing that makes this particularly strange is that I have another dll that has exactly the same references and code and it works perfectly. (only some filenames are different).

Any thoughts? Thanks for helping me out with this.

-t

Comment: Are the file extensions the same for the file names in each application?

Answer (score 0):

Something to at least try:

```
theConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                   "Data Source='" & gProgramFilesPath & "';" & _
                   "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1'"
```

I.e. use quotes (apostrophes above) around the value for `Data Source` in case of characters that disrupt connection string parsing.

Also, isn't `IMEX` only used with the Excel IISAM and not the Text and HTML IISAMs?

Mixing ADO and DAO in one program is odd, but hopefully unrelated.

Comment: Thanks User and Bob. I've tried your suggestions but no change. Still get the "Excel" err. User, all the relevant files are .mdb files, but I don't get that far. I've checked the gProgramFilesPath and replaced with a string...same err. I've removed the trailing backslash from the string, same error. I appreciate your help...and I know there's not much here to go on. That's why it's driving me nuts. LOL.

Comment: @user1422047 Your connection string appears to be foe opening a delimited text file, not an access database. I asked about the file extension because if you're using an extension that is not in the registry value `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\DisabledExtensions` you will get errors reading the file.

Comment: I've solved the problem. My source csv file (from another vendor) had changed the heading text in one of the columns. Because I was using a schema file, the silently failed, causing the error. I then found that the ImportMixedTypes setting in HKLM\Software\Wow6432\Node\Microsoft\\Jet\4.0\text was being set to "" by something. Now I reset that reg value to "Text" before I try to instantiate the object, then reset it to whatever it was before I started, and everything is working. Thanks to all to helped. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: If you have a schema.ini file then the IMEX value means nothing.  Of course its default can't be corrupt in the registry either, or you'll get an error just as you saw.